# How to aggregate strings with JPA?

Tags: java, string, hibernate, jpa, aggregate

Base Data:

```
DEPTNO ENAME
------ ------
    20 SMITH
    30 ALLEN
    30 WARD
    20 JONES
    30 MARTIN
    30 BLAKE
    10 CLARK
    20 SCOTT
    10 KING
    30 TURNER
    20 ADAMS
    30 JAMES
    20 FORD
    10 MILLER
```

Desired Output:

```
DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
------ ---------
    10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
    20 SMITH,FORD,ADAMS,SCOTT,JONES
    30 ALLEN,BLAKE,MARTIN,TURNER,JAMES,WARD
```

I have tried this jpql query:

```
 SELECT deptno, new list(ename) as employees
 FROM dept_emp
```

However an exception is raised:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: new near line 1, column 15

**JPA 2.1**
**Hibernate 4.3.1**

**See also:**
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/24570617/363573

Answer (score 1):

Firstly to use jpa ,  you should entity class.

```
@Entity
class Employee {
   int deptNo;
   String name;

}
```

Query is

```
SELECT e.deptNo , new list(e.name) FROM Employee e GROUP BY e.deptNo
```

Comment: Even with group by, I have the exception.

Comment: What is error ? can  you write stacktrace. Also can you share your entity class?

Comment: I have the same exception as in my post.

Comment: can you share your entity classes in post?

Comment: Where does ```new list()``` come from?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to implement UI-related functionality (how data should be displayed) in the persistence layer, using a JPQL query. That's a bad idea. Retrieve the data in the UI layer using the persistence layer, and then format the data as you wish. For example:

```
List<Employee> employees = em.createQuery("select e from Employee e").getResultList();
```

And in your presentation layer:

```
Multimap<String, Employee> employeesByDepartment = 
    Multimaps.index(employees, Employee::getDepartmentNumber);
for (String departmentNumber : employeesByDepartment.keySet()) {
    System.out.print(departmentNumber);
    System.out.print("\t");
    System.out.println(Joiner.on(", ").join(employeesByDepartment.get(departmentNumber)));
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution described here. In my case, it's terribly slow because they are more than 3 departments.

Comment: What is slow? What's the relationship between the number of departments and the slowness?

Comment: If the number of department is high, the screen takes more time to show up.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions. Obviously, if the screen loads 5 million rows, it will be slower than if it load 5 rows. But whatever the way you load the data, that will be true. So, how many rows do you load? What is slow? The query execution, the creation of the Multimap? Displaying the data? How many columns are there in the employee table?

Comment: How many rows? : 100; What is slow? again, the screen takes time to appear to final user; How many columns? just the ones in my post: 2

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
SELECT deptno,  STRING_AGG(ename, ', ') as employees
FROM dept_emp
GROUP BY deptno
```

[Refer to this](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/)